# Dynamic select in Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabledit

How can i select avatar dynamic from DB Table instead of adding manually as 1, 2,3 etc

```
$('#example6').Tabledit({
    url: 'example.php',
    $('#example6').Tabledit({
        url: 'example.php',
        columns: {
            identifier: [0, 'id'],
            editable: [[1, 'name'],[2, 'avatar', '{"1": "A", "2": "B", "3": "C"}']]
   }
});
```

Comment: I believe some elaboration is needed? "Select avatar dynamic(ally)". What do you mean *exactly*? You have an array of elements. Do you have a specific element that you want to select from your array, going by some specific logic, or do you wish to iterate through the entire array and get them all *dyamically*? You could loop through your array and have an incrementor be the index pointer of your array. I think that's all I can give you without any further specifics.

Comment: If you wish to *"do something"* upon a selection of your avatar(s), e.g. a user clicks one of the printed avatars or whatever, you can use `$(this)` selector and apply some logic around that in terms of knowing what specific element you're selecting.

Comment: I do not know a lot about tabledit however nesting `$('#example6').Tabledit({` inside another `$('#example6').Tabledit({` seems wrong, and your example code has a syntax error as a result of that.d  perhaps provide as much of a working example as you can, including the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied a lot of markup, but to answer the question, you could do a call to get it via ajax.  Here, I have a non-existing "mythings.json" and use a default on fail, you would need a proper URL and get data from that.

```js
var athings = '';
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "mythings.json"
  }).done(function(data) {
    athings = data;
    dotable();
  }).fail(function() {
    console.log("failed do default");
    athings = '{"1": "Apples", "2": "Beef", "3": "Candy"}';
    dotable();
  });

  function dotable() {
    $('#example6').Tabledit({
      url: 'example.php',
      columns: {
        identifier: [0, 'id'],
        editable: [
          [1, 'name'],
          [2, 'avatar', athings]
        ]
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://getbootstrapadmin.com/remark/global/vendor/jquery-tabledit/jquery.tabledit.min.js?v4.0.2"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example6">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Avatar</th>
        <th class="tabledit-toolbar-column"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="1" class="danger">
        <td><span class="tabledit-span tabledit-identifier">1</span><input class="tabledit-input tabledit-identifier" type="hidden" name="id" value="1" disabled=""></td>
        <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span" style="display: inline;">markcellbites</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="username" value="markcell" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>
        <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span" style="display: inline;">Captain America</span>

        </td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%;" class="tabledit-view-mode">
          <div class="tabledit-toolbar btn-toolbar" style="text-align: left;">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" style="float: none;"><button type="button" class="tabledit-edit-button btn btn-sm btn-default" style="float: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button><button type="button" class="tabledit-delete-button btn btn-sm btn-default" style="float: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-save-button btn btn-sm btn-success" style="float: none; display: none;">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-confirm-button btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="display: none; float: none;">Confirm</button>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-restore-button btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="display: none; float: none;">Restore</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="2" class="danger">
        <td><span class="tabledit-span tabledit-identifier">2</span><input class="tabledit-input tabledit-identifier" type="hidden" name="id" value="2" disabled=""></td>
        <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">dotz</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="username" value="dotz" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>

        <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">Captain America</span>

        </td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%;" class="tabledit-view-mode">
          <div class="tabledit-toolbar btn-toolbar" style="text-align: left;">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" style="float: none;"><button type="button" class="tabledit-edit-button btn btn-sm btn-default" style="float: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button><button type="button" class="tabledit-delete-button btn btn-sm btn-default" style="float: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-save-button btn btn-sm btn-success" style="display: none; float: none;">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-confirm-button btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="display: none; float: none;">Confirm</button>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-restore-button btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="display: none; float: none;">Restore</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="3" class="danger">
        <td><span class="tabledit-span tabledit-identifier">3</span><input class="tabledit-input tabledit-identifier" type="hidden" name="id" value="3" disabled=""></td>
        <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">zikospeed</span><input class="tabledit-input form-control input-sm" type="text" name="username" value="zikospeed" style="display: none;" disabled=""></td>

        <td class="tabledit-view-mode"><span class="tabledit-span">Black Widow</span>

        </td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap; width: 1%;" class="tabledit-view-mode">
          <div class="tabledit-toolbar btn-toolbar" style="text-align: left;">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" style="float: none;"><button type="button" class="tabledit-edit-button btn btn-sm btn-default" style="float: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button><button type="button" class="tabledit-delete-button btn btn-sm btn-default" style="float: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-save-button btn btn-sm btn-success" style="display: none; float: none;">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-confirm-button btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="display: none; float: none;">Confirm</button>
            <button type="button" class="tabledit-restore-button btn btn-sm btn-warning" style="display: none; float: none;">Restore</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Martin i mean by dynamic(ally)  suppose that i have table and avatar is the table name so instead of typing options  manually like [2, 'avatar', '{"1": "A", "2": "B", "3": "C"}']  i wonder is there any possibility in Jquery Tableedit that to fetch avatar as selection from Database Table Avatar